# How do I close a GitHub issue without making a commit?

Tags: git, github

I thought there would be a simple way to do this, but I'm really having a hard time finding any answers in any search I make. I have some issues that I need to close because we decided that it is not really an issue, so I need to close it. I already know how to close an issue with commit message, but I can't find any other way to do this.

Answer (score 48):

You can close an issue through the GitHub web interface when you're viewing the issue. The "Close Issue" button is to the left of the "comment" button under the comment box. I believe you need to be a collaborator on a repo to close an issue.

[image: Close GitHub Issue]

Comment: You can also close issues you opened.

Comment: Looks like the permissions were off. It works now, thanks!

Comment: Splendid, glad you figured it out!

Comment: Can only close if you're a collaborator.